# Why are there already some Users when first creating a database? (SQL Server 2017, SSMS 17.9)

Tags: sql-server, database, authentication, ssms

With Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, either executing SQL Commands (e.g. `CREATE DATABASE XYZ`) or through GUI to create a fresh-new database, the database ends up with some default Users (see picture below), e.g. `dbo`, current domain user, `guest`, `sys`.

Is this the default behavior of SQL Server? Is there anyway to control this behavior? (e.g. not including the current domain user, who is using the computer with SSMS; or having to include some users)

Another strange thing is in the list of users, one can see `tester222`, which I created for testing long time ago, and this name is no longer there in "SQL Server Instance\Security\Logins" in Object Explorer. How could it just now surface in the list?

[image: Sample Database]

Comment: Any database created copies the template of the `model` database; so all those users will be in there. The `dbo` user is the database owner, `sys` and `public` are both part of the set up as well (`sys` is where all the system object lie).

Comment: Users != Logins.  Logins are at the server level (Server\Security\Logins), users are at the database level (Databases\<DB>\Security\Users).  Users are tied to a specific login.  You can delete a login, and not the user; so you'd see the user in the database, but it would be orphaned and not belonging to a login.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Larnu.

New databases are created based *the* model database. See example below:

[Model Database in SQL Server 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JG1wa.png)

If changing, say, the list of default users in this model database, every new database when created will inherit that list of user.

From Microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/model-database?view=sql-server-2017

> The model database is used as the template for all databases created
>   on an instance of SQL Server. Because tempdb is created every time SQL
>   Server is started, the model database must always exist on a SQL
>   Server system. The entire contents of the model database, including
>   database options, are copied to the new database. Some of the settings
>   of model are also used for creating a new tempdb during start up, so
>   the model database must always exist on a SQL Server system.